# Dynamically change highlighted dates in Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

hi 
I have a Jquery Datepicker object that is created fine with no highlighted dates and a particular minDate.

I want to add a highlights to this datepicker based on an AJAX call made by the user, but the only way I can see to change the highlights is adding a function to the beforeShowDay event, which is set on setup.

How can I change this function on an existing datepicker and force it to redraw so that I get my new date(s) to be highlighted.

Many thanks everyone.

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right the only way I could find to do this is to use the destroy method then redraw the picker with the new method attached to it. If anyone knows a better way of doing this please add it and I'll give you the answer.
Thanks

EDIT: Code...

Setup the picker...

```
    var datePickerSettings = {
        beforeShowDate: beforeShowDateMethod
    };

    var alternateDatePickerSettings = {
        beforeShowDate: beforeShowDateMethodAlternate
    };

    $('#mydiv').datepicker(datePickerSettings);
```

Then once callback is complete

```
 $('#mydiv').datepicker('destroy')
 $('#mydiv').datepicker(alternateDatePickerSettings);
```

In the end I didn't use the date picker as the requirements changed, but this should solve the problem

Dave

Answer (score 0):

There is the setDate method of the datepicker. I cannot link directly but it is here http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ under methods

Comment: setDate sets the selected date of the picker, that's not what I am trying to do. I need to add highlights to specific dates.